# How to write an link for email in repository class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to figure out how to write a dynamic URL (a.k.a. activationlink) in a repository class.

Here's what was working with but I'm not sure how to do the "http://mysite.com" dynamically:

```
private static void SendActivationEmail(User user)
{
    string ActivationLink = "http://mysite.com" +
                              user.Username + "/" + user.NewEmailKey;

    var message = new MailMessage("email@email.com", user.Email)
    {
        Subject = "Activate your account",
        Body = ActivationLink
    };

    var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.email.com");

    client.Send(message);

}
```

Comment: links work using the <a href=  tag..

Comment: what is the value of ActivationLink string you are getting and what else would you like to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your case you could do something like this

```
String.Format("<a href=/"{0}/{1}/{2}">Click Here To Activate</a>",
      user.Username, user.NewEmailKey);
```

if you know want the user to be redirected to a Activate web page via a url. then you would want to format the link via a query string 
this is an example use it how you need to to fit your UseCase

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host`

instead of `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`

For your local dev environment you will be getting `localhost`, but when you deploy this to some web server, this would correctly update itself to the hosted web server url.

Ideally, you would have some path that would contain the querystring and then corresponding code in page load to validate and use the querystring.

Example:

```
<br/>"+HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host + @"/AccountValidate.aspx?id=SomeId"
```

Note: You could use the HttpContext.Current.Request.Url also and that would redirect you to the current page with querystring:

```
<br/>"+HttpContext.Current.Request.Url + "?user=SomeUser " .... same for user.NewEmailKey does this make sense..??
```

And then in page load of AccountValidate.aspx or current page:

```
string user = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["user"]);
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
... //Code here to inform the user of successful activation
```

Comment: DJ KRAZE, you have three params but are passing two.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that .. that's because I left it up to the OP to decide if he wanted to use the last variable or not.. but I am sure that the OP has gotten the drift of what I was saying..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use <a href...> and set the body as html. Try this:

```
private static void SendActivationEmail(User user)
{
    string activationLink = string.Concat("<a href='ht", "tp://mysite.com/", user.Username, "/", user.NewEmailKey, "'>Activate Here</a>");
    var message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("email@email.com", user.Email)
    {
        Subject = "Activate your account",
        Body = activationLink,
        IsBodyHtml = true
    };
    var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.email.com");
    client.Send(message);
}
```